# Excel array formula with slope function

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I would like to know why the below formula doesn't work:

[image: Screen shot of spreadsheet]

It is an array formula that I am using with the slope function. I would like to take the slope of the data points with the top 100 and 10000 gpm.

Comment: It doesn't like your merged cells - try to re-work your sheet to remove the merges.

Answer (score 0):

Column B and C seem to have been merged, as also D and E.

Please google some examples of SLOPE, such as https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/slope.php  or  https://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-slope-function.html

I found the following to work;  are they close to your expected results?--

```
=SLOPE(A3:A15,B3:B15)    result is 282.5076

=SLOPE(A3:A15,D3:D15)    result is 305.1815
```